# C# Activator.CreateInstance Error

Tags: c#, runtimeexception

Main class ....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            string className = "Demo";
            string namespaceName = "ConsoleApplication1";
            var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Other class ....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1{
    class Demo{
        public void printClassName() {
            Console.WriteLine("Demo");
        }
    }
}
```

This simple program has runtime error at

`var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, className);` line.

```
System.TypeLoadException {"Could not load type 'Demo' from assembly 'ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.":"Demo"}
```

Please help me to solve this error!.

Answer (score 5):

[`Activator.CreateInstance(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't do what you think it does.

The first parameter is the *assembly* name. The second parameter is the fully-qualified *type* name.

So you should have:

```
string className = "ConsoleApplication1.Demo";
string assemblyName = "ConsoleApplication1";
var myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, className);
```

(Assuming it's compiled into an assembly called `ConsoleApplication1` of course.)

If you're able to get a handle to the `Assembly` in a different way, however, you can use `Assembly.GetType(string)` and then `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)`.

Comment: i saw you talking about performance somewhere on web.. can u pls explain here with Activator.CreateInstance and new Demo() ..

Comment: @vishalsharma: I don't know what you mean, but it doesn't seem relevant to this question as nothing about performance was mentioned.

Comment: i mean.. what are the performance impact between newing up the object and creating object using Activator.CreateInstance ...

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution to the create issue.
You need to assign all the class types with an initial value so the parameter-less constructor can work normally.